# Importing float data from csv in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I have a csv file, which has one row with many data. The problem is that this data is float, something like this (7.66907027311089).
I use this code to import this data:

```
with open('Sygnal2.txt','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in plots:
        y.append(int(float(row[0])))
```

Even when I use `float`, when I print `y` I got a list of no float numbers. Any ideas how to change it?

Comment: why `int`? Use `y.append(float(row[0]))`

Comment: Ok, post it as an answer. Thanks man :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting twice - first you make a `float` from your `string`, and then an `int` from your `float` - simply do:

```
y.append(float(row[0]))
```